# Doctrine: Should this be a Many-to-Many?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

So I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine and am unsure of a relationship. The goal of the site is to allow users to browse and upload stories. A feature I'm trying to implement is that users can extend other stories. For example, if I like a fantasy story and want to write a story set in the same world, I can extend it so that it is a Child of the original Parent story. There is no limit to how many parents or children a story can have.

I thought at first that it would be a self referencing many-to-many relationship, with property called `$parents` and one called `$children`, but I'm not sure how I would actually implement that. More conceptually than in terms of code.

What I have now is (in Story.orm.yml):

```
parents:
  targetEntity: Story
    inversedBy: children
    joinTable:
      name: parents
      joinColumns:
        child_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
      inverseJoinColumn:
        parent_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
```

Is that a correct implementation?

Are there any other alternatives to a many-to-many relationship that would be better suited to something like this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should have [**OneToMany** self-referencing relationship](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing). I think so because I'm suppose that you are extending ONE story (parent), and it can has MANY (child) stories. As you say:

> it is a Child of the original Parent story

It looks like single inheritance (not [multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). However, a story can have multiple parents.

Comment: @shaqb4 I think, that `ManyToMany` can bring additional complexity and headache in this case. But perhaps, I simply got used to think of single inheritance since I generally write PHP code ;).

Comment: Would the complexity be from implementing it, or actually using it in the application? Do you mind giving an example of when a many-to-many would be more difficult? Haha, understandable :)

Comment: @shaqb4 you can try both solutions and decide what is more suitable for your idea.